# How resize sub views along with super views

Tags: iphone

I want to resize super view in different orientations with subviews.
I have an image view and I am adding different subviews in this image with layering.
Please tell me how can I resize all parts of image on different orientation.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an image inside an uiview for example, if you rotate the uiview the content inside will change with it.

same for resizing. 
i do my resizing manually when the orientation changes ( i use an observer to listen for changes on the orientation, and manually change my size using CGAffineTransform )